# Customizing user login in Windows 7

Tags: windows

I need to implement a security requirement in one of our Window 7 workstation. The requirement is that in the login screen, the user will type-in their details and if the the account or password is invalid, there should be no message to be displayed.

and in the event of successful login, it is required to prompt a simple details showing the last successful logins and failed attempts.

I was advised that Windows login script can fulfill this requirement.
If anyone have done this, please share the steps.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Active Directory environment or local logins? Note that the login dialog is running in a secured desktop, to prevent other programs from stealing the password information.

Comment: Hi MSalters, thanks for your reply, the machine is not join to domain. it is an isolated machine. the requirement is just to NOT give the user a hint that he is typing an invalid account or password. More over, if the login is successful, the system should show a short review of his previous successful or failed login attempts.

Comment: Other question: Windows 7 Home/Pro/Ultimate ? IIRC the home version shows the user list with associated icons, but the Pro version doesn't.

Comment: You can't change the logon screen behaviour with a login script.  You'd need to write a credential provider.  This is difficult, and too broad for SO.  There is a third-party product called [pGINA](http://pgina.org/index.html) which might help, though I've never used it so I don't know whether it will meet your needs.

Comment: However, it isn't possible to make the observed behaviour the same for a failed logon attempt as for a successful one; if the logon attempt fails, the user must be prompted again, and if it succeeds, the logon has to begin.  So suppressing the "invalid username or password" message is completely pointless.  You'd be wasting your time.

Comment: Thank you MSalters and Harry Johnston for your reply, I will check further regarding pGINA. thanks.